# Switching Between External Aliases Without Re-Writing Code?

Tags: c#, alias, extern

```
extern alias dll1;
extern alias dll2;    
...

public void DoStuff1(){
    dll1::NameSpace.Class.Method();
}
public void DoStuff2(){
    dll2::NameSpace.Class.Method();
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is:

```
public void DoStuff(alias a){
    a::NameSpace.Class.Method();
}
```

*alias* does not appear to be usable like this.

Addendum: dll1 and dll2 are different versions of the same dll.

Comment: Did the reflection code help?  Was it what you had in mind?  Instead of passing an alias argument to your function, you'd pass a string that describes the correct dll that you need, although you'd have to figure out the details of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using dynamic in .Net 4.0.

The combination of using external aliases with dynamic was the cleanest and simplest solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep code from different aliases in different files, and use partial classes in each file. (Partial classes allow you to write code for the same class in different files.)  That should do it.

For instance:

File 1:

```
extern alias dll1;

partial class foo
{

 public void DoStuff1(){
        dll1::NameSpace.Class.Method();
}

}
```

File 2:

```
 extern alias dll2;


 partial class foo
 {
    public void DoStuff2(){
        dll2::NameSpace.Class.Method();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Eugenio, the solution you posted still requires writing two different DoStuff functions.  I want to be able to write one DoStuff function and specify which dll it uses.  I added to my original post that dll1 and dll2 are different versions of the same dll. Thanks!

Comment: If what you are trying to access are instance methods, you could pass in an instance of the correct class.  You could rewrite static methods as instance methods.  Otherwise, I'm sure reflection could solve your problem but not without some verbose code and some overhead.

Comment: In this type of situation, would you recommend using reflection over external aliases?  I don't know anything about reflection, what advantages does it have?

Comment: I have used reflection very little, but here's what i know:  You can pass in a string that describes the full name of a namespace/class in order to create objects or call methods in that namespace/class.  I guess that you can also specify which dll you are talking about in the string when the namespace is ambiguous.  Look up info on the Type class. If i can find some code, i'll post it.  The advantage of reflection is that anything is possible.  It exposes the underlying structure of the code to you, but it is sometimes too abstract and leads to cumbersome code, which is what we don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some reflection code.  It is based on code given in O'Reilly's C# Cookbook by Hilyard and Teilhet.  I adapted it and removed some stuff, and I haven't tested it, but if you use reflection, something like this would work for you.  You would just have to pass in the correct assembly name (still haven't figured out how to deal with dlls with same namespace, but there has to be a way), and the correct class and method names, and this function will call the appropriate method for you.

A problem with reflection is that you lose some type checking, since you have to work with generic objects, and you have to use strings to represent namespaces, types, and members.

```
    object InvokeMethod(string assembly, string type, string method, object[] parameters)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);
        Type classtype = asm.GetType(type, true, false);
        object dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(classtype);

        MethodInfo invokedMethod = classtype.GetMethod(method);

        return invokedMethod.Invoke(dynamicObject,parameters);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make an enum which will specify which alias to use? Then you'd have something like

```
public void DoStuff(int a){
    if(a==0)
        dll1:Namespace.Class.Method()
    else if(a==1)
        dll2:Namespace.Class.Method()
}
```