# External Alias vs. Reflection vs. System.Addin For Multi-DLL Testing?

Tags: c#, dll

Let's say I have two DLL's, one is a development DLL, another is a production DLL.  I want to write software that compares the results of various functions from each DLL.

Currently, I am using external aliases, which is a pretty nice solution, but  it is requiring a lot of code duplication (this is the type of problem I'm encountering: [Switching Between External Aliases Without Re-Writing Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315571/switching-between-external-aliases-without-re-writing-code))

So now, I'm considering looking into using reflection or System.Addin (treat DLL's as plugins).  Before I start figuring out which would be better for my software, I was wondering if you all have any experience with this type of problem, and what solution you decided to use.  This is a very critical part of the system I'm developing, so getting it to work the best way possible is important.

I really appreciate any comments, thanks!

Edit: Bottom line, I imagine there has to be a "best practice" way to test the results from two DLL's.  This has to be something that people do quite frequently (I would guess).

Comment: Would `dynamic` suffice?

Comment: dynamic is only available in VS2010?  I will have to explore that option soon when I get that installed on my box.  Thanks :)

Comment: [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (now part of the .Net Framework 4) can help you. It allow you to auto discover concrete classes of an interface in all dll of a folder (it's only one of the possibilities)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Unity or another dependency injection framework?  This is a primary use case for such a framework.  Unity can be found at ([Unity on Codeplex](http://unity.codeplex.com/)) and is a Microsoft Patterns and Practices project.